# Entity Framework and Properties of Type dynamic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6.1

we are currently switching from LinqToSQL to EF. By now we were using `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<T>` for running more complex SQL statements. Sometimes we have types for T where some properties are of type `dynamic`.

In LinqToSQL this worked just fine. `Entities.Database.SqlQuery<T>` somehow returns `null` for those properties, although it's the same query.

Is there a possibility to continue using the model classes and not changing the dynamic properies?